# Update field about size of nested array

Tags: javascript

I would like to create additional field - `"grid.height"` for each element of table `components`. It's done withing this script:

```
db.myTestdb.updateMany(
    {'model.components.type': "FIXED"},
    {$set: 
        {"model.components.$.grid" : 
            {
                "height": 1,
            }
        }
    }
)
```

In the next step I would like to update the `height` field about size of some other table (e.g. elements) which is nested in `components` array. I created something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
db.myTestdb.updateMany(
    {'model.components.type': "FIXED"},
    {$set: { "model.components.$.grid.height": {"$size": "model.components.elements}}}
)
```

Problem is with this formula: `{"$size": "model.components.elements}}}`.
Can you help me to make it work?

Comment: regular update query will not support aggregation operators also can not allow internal fields value of another field. you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) but `$` positional will not work you have to deal with other aggregation operators to update in array.. for more specific answer please post some example document.

Comment: @turivishal I updated my post about example document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular update query will not support aggregation operators also can not allow internal fields as value of another field. you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) but `$` positional will not work in aggregation update, you have to deal with other aggregation operators to update in array,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `components`
- `$size` to get elements size
- prepare `grid` object and set `height` field
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object and `grid` object

```
db.myTestdb.updateMany(
  { "model.components.type": "FIXED" },
  [{
    $set: {
      "model.components": {
        $map: {
          input: "$model.components",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.type", "FIXED"] },
                  {
                    grid: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this.grid",
                        { height: { $size: "$$this.elements" } }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_hM1cLQ0Mcg)

Comment: thank you @turivishal , it works fine, only in your example should be update instead of updateMany as it is in the playground  you create. Now I have one more question. I want to create inside the grid secondTable which will copy ids from the model.components.emelents.
I create a second $map to loop throug elements but it doesn't work. Te example is  here: [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GQwxkDieToG) . Do you know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Sure. In the example I presented it looks like it is only copy of the previous table but I wanted to keep it simple. Normally these tables will differ but the id's need to be the same. Here expected result is in configuration tab: [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C2TFNcoGMpC)

Comment: i have improved answer, and check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yy1kPEZnak2) for your newTable field.. you can remove `height` property object if its not needed..

Comment: this is not what I meant cause it is an exact copy of the previous table. But it's my fault, should have been more explicit. Here is the link to expected result. I updated that about a "startPosition" field which should be incremented for each element in new table. [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xIUSug3uX8t)

Comment: check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VSVTebN8Fm_)

Comment: You're awsome - it would take me a lot of time to figure out this. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. I see that after your changes filtering by `"model.components.type": "FIXED"` doesn't work and the new fields are added to each component. Link with provided model is here [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QcNhRtMchVQ)